# Filtering by source in Google Analytics Data Studio shows no data

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

When I try to filter by the betika.com source filter, it doesn't show any data at all.

Here are two screen shots: one with the filter configuration and the other with the result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never used data studio before, but just based on the documentation, you may not need to filter by source.  https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066?hl=en says each filter is automatically associated with the data source of the component.

Comment: "Source" usually means UTM source. I think Stephen is right, there's no direct filtering on data source in Data Studio.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, but when I filter other referrals, it works.. :(